# Creating Google Calendar event from received Gmail message

Tags: gmail, google-calendar

Is it possible to create a calendar appointment from an email message? I'm sure in the past it would give you a link in the right column if it detected a date in the message, but this no longer seems to happen.

**edit**

I actually want to create an event from an email I received containing details of an event.

Comment: Note that this feature behaves differently depending on if you are using "Google Apps" or the standard Gmail (not Google Apps). This can confuse some users.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When viewing the email, click "More Actions" in the button bar and choose "Create Event" from the dropdown.

[image: create event]

Comment: Thanks - weirdly that never appeared when I tried. I just changed my google account settings to US english from UK english though and it appears now (after creating a new session). reverting stopped it from appearing again.

Comment: Yes, that's the way it's supposed to work - http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=47803&cbid=-z4iyo6mxgb6r&src=cb&lev=%20answer. However it would be nice if it worked in other languages, like UK English!

Comment: This isn't working for me, though I've seen blog posts about it as recently as a few weeks ago. Did gmail just cancel this very useful feature? https://i.imgur.com/I0VWHeP.png

Answer (score 4):

Newly launched: [Add events to Google Calendar from Gmail](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2013/05/add-events-to-google-calendar-from-gmail.html)

> If you do a lot of scheduling over email, it's now a little bit easier to create events directly from your Gmail. Starting today, dates and times within emails are lightly underlined: click them to schedule that conference call or lunch date without ever leaving Gmail.
>
> [image: screen shot]
>
> When you click on one of these underlined dates, you’ll be able to preview your schedule for the day and change the title, date or time of the event. Clicking “Add to Calendar” will do exactly that -- add the event to your calendar, and for extra convenience, the calendar event will include a link back to the original email.
>
> This new feature is rolling out over the next week to everyone with the English (US) language. We'll be adding other languages soon, so stay tuned.

When you create an event from an underlined date/time within the message, the above Gmail feature will conveniently link to the original message from within the newly-created event.  However, for some reason, if you use the drop-down menu to "Create event", then you do not get any link.

Answer (score 0):

When composing new email, there is a hyperlink named `'Invitation'` next to `'Attach a file'  Clicking on it should open a popup to fill out appointment details.  After which it inserts the calender appointement into your email body.

Comment: sorry, I wasn't clear. i would actually like to create an event from a received email